# How can one capture user login success on react admin v3.1?

Tags: react-admin, admin-on-rest

I am trying to capture a user login success by looking for any auth actions but I don't see any in the redux dev tool that has anything to do with AUTH? I want to use this to make an API call to fetch more data.

I do see stuff like RA\REGISTER_RESOURCE etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to those in your saga:

```
import {USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, SET_SIDEBAR_VISIBILITY} from 'react-admin'
```

However, the new updated version of react v3.5.3 Git ride of those and relay on hooks